# ¿Cómo aplicar diferentes clases para cada segundo valor de búcle foreach?

Tags: php

Como ejemplo pongo esta bucle foreach:

```
$colores = array(
    "rojo",
    "verde",
    "azul",
    "amarillo"
); 

foreach ($colores as $valor) {
    echo '<span class="clase">' . $valor . '</span>';
}
```

Al `<span>`, en vez de clase="clase" quiero aplicar a cada segundo valor una clase:

```
class="izquierda"
class="derecha"
```

Para que cada segundo valor esté alineado a la izquierda y cada segundo restante, a la derecha.

Comment: Lukas, la respuesta era bastante facil (no quito crédito a Carmen, por supuesto). Que fue lo que intentaste y fracasó?

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con "cada segundo valor"? Todos han entendido que te refieres a los valores pares (posiblemente sea eso) pero me desconcierta lo de _Para que cada segundo valor esté alineado a la izquierda y cada segundo restante, a la derecha._  El segundo valor del array es "verde" pero ¿el segundo restante cual es?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes controlar la posición mientras recorres el array, y ver si es par o impar.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($colores), $i++) {
   if ($i%2==0) {
    echo '<span class="izquierda">' . $colores[$i] . '</span>';
   } else {
     echo '<span class="derecha">' . $colores[$i] . '</span>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Probablemente sea mejor poner el `count()` fuera del bucle para no tener que calcularlo cada vez. También sería interesante usar una variable del tipo `$class_id` y asignarle izq/dcha y luego decir `echo '<span class="$class_id" ...`.

Answer (score 5):

Basándome en la respuesta de @Carmen, esto haría lo mismo pero con menos líneas de código:

```
$total = count($colores);

for ($i = 0; $i < $total, $i++) { 
   $class = ($i%2) ? 'derecha' : 'izquierda'; // Edit: Optimización sugerida por @fedorqui 
   echo '<span class="' . $class . '">' . $colores[$i] . '</span>';   
}
```

Además, puedes aplicar distintos estilos a elementos html usando únicamente css usando la pseudo-clase :nth-child y los valores odd (impar) y even (par)

Por ejemplo:

```css
.element {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
}

.element:nth-child(odd) {
    text-align: left;
}

.element:nth-child(even) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
     <div class="element">izquierda</div>
     <div class="element">derecha</div>
     <div class="element">izquierda</div>
     <div class="element">derecha</div>
     <div class="element">izquierda</div>
     <div class="element">derecha</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qué bueno lo de `nth-child`, no lo sabía. Puestos a usar el operador ternario y potencialidades, puedes asumir que `$i%2` devuelve valor True/False y poner `$class = ($i%2) ? 'derecha' : 'izquierda';`.